# Using xUnit and Moq to mock repository with dependencies in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am trying to use xUnit and Moq to test my repository but I am having trouble with setting up my mock repository.

This is my test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, null)]
public async Task GetLevelsAsync_ReturnsArgumentNullException(int appId, string year)
{
    //Arrange
    IOptions<Settings> options = Options.Create(set);
    Mock<ILoggerFactory> _loggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
    Mock<ILogger<GeoRepository>> _loggerGeoRepository = new Mock<ILogger<GeoRepository>>();
    Mock<DataProviderFactory> _dataProviderFactory = new Mock<DataProviderFactory>(_loggerFactory, options);
    GeoRepository geo = new GeoRepository (_loggerGeoRepository.Object, options, _dataProviderFactory.Object);

    //Act
    Func<Task> action = async () => await geo.GetLevelsByYear(appId, year);

    //Assert
    var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(action);
    Assert.Contains("Value cannot be null", ex.Message);
}
```

This is my respository:

```
public class GeoRepository : BaseRepository, IGeoRepository
{
    public GeoRepository(ILogger<GeoRepository> logger, 
        IOptions<Settings> settings,
        DataProviderFactory dpFactory) : base(logger, settings, dpFactory)
    {
    }

    public async Task<List<Year>> GetLevelsByYear(int appId, string year)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(year))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(year));

        var result = new List<Level>();

        var parameters = new { AppId = appId, Year = year};

        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE AppId = @AppId AND DataYear = @Year";

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_settings.SqlServerConnString))
        {
            try
            {
                result = db.Query<Level>(sql, parameters).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Error querying levels by year", new { appId, year});
                throw;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error message:

```
System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Project.Services.Data.API.Infrastructure.DataProviderFactory.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
Moq.Mock`1[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory]
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsWrapper`1[Project.Services.Data.API.Settings]
(Parameter 'constructorArguments')
---- System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.DataProviderFactoryProxy' not found.
```

This is my DataProviderFactory that I'm having trouble mocking, please see error message above:

```
public class DataProviderFactory
{
    private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private IOptions<Settings> _settings;
    public DataProviderFactory(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<Settings> settings)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        _settings = settings?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));

    }
    public DataProvider GetProvider(DatabaseProvider provider)
    {
        switch (provider)
        {
            case DatabaseProvider.SqlServer:
                {
                    var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SqlProvider>();
                    return new SqlProvider(logger, _settings);
                }
            case DatabaseProvider.Snowflake:
                {
                    var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SnowFlakeProvider>();
                    return new SnowFlakeProvider(logger, _settings);
                }
            default:
                {
                    var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SqlProvider>();
                    return new SqlProvider(logger, _settings);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intentionally mean to supply `action` as `Func<Task>` when the return value is `Task<List<Year>>`? Also, it seems like you're creating a `Func` (an encapsulated function) into the `Assert.ThrowsAsync` but it doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney Thank you for your comment. I am having trouble mocking the DataProviderFactory. I have updated my question with the test error message.

Comment: From the error message you are receiving, your Mock is not supplying any constructor arguments as is defined in your implementation. It seems as though you'll need to supply the constructor parameters for the `DataProviderFactory` in your Mock - you could also create an interface and Mock that as opposed to the implementation itself.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I have supplied the constructor arguments for DataProviderFactory. Please see updated code and error message in question, thank you.

Comment: The constructor arguments you're supplying is incorrect - looking at the error message it's indicating you're providing the `Moq` wrapper of the instance (e.g, `_loggerFactory`) but not the actual instance (e.g, `_loggerFactory.Object`)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because the error message returns the null parameter in the Year case. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'year').

the validation of the error in the correct way would be like this...

```
        //Assert
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(action);
```

and that alone does not need to validate the exception message because the assert itself plays this by validating the error type

yes that means that if you open any other exception at runtime it will not be considered as a valid test

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble mocking the DataProviderFactory. I have updated my question with the test error message.